# click event for itemViewClass of a collectionView which is directly defined inside the handlebars file

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Here's my code:

```
{{#collection contentBinding="someArray"}}
  {{#view valueBinding="view.content"}}
    <a>{{view.value}}</a>
  {{/view}}
{{/collection}}
```

I want to add a click event for the above view tag, How should I accomplish this? I tried the following way but of no use:

```
{{#collection contentBinding="someArray"}}
  {{#view valueBinding="view.content" clickBinding="someFunction"}}
    <a>{{view.value}}</a>
  {{/view}}
{{/collection}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `<a {{action eventHandler target="view"}}>`, `eventHandler` being a function in the view that takes an `event`. You can pass a context if necessary: `<a {{action eventHandler this target="view"}}>`, (the current handlebars context in the case of `this`) which would be accessible with `event.context` in the handler.

Comment: Thanks this works :) , but will this {{action}} helper works for other tags too ?

Comment: Yup, totally. By the way, if you use the ember routing architecture (see http://trek.github.com/ for details), then `{{action eventHandler}}` without a `target` defined would by default look for `eventHandler` in the current route (or an ancestor). If the handler is an event transition, you could use `{{action eventHandler href=true}}` which would fill in `href` with the proper routing path -- this would only work with `<a>` tags.

Comment: That's great ! One more thing can we do this ? {{action someFunction target ="MyApp.router.someController"}} coz sometimes we need to handle events across the controllers.

Comment: This may work now, but will be deprecated in 1.8 DEPRECATION: Action handlers implemented directly on views are deprecated in favor of action handlers on an `actions` object ( action: `clearNotification` on <App.NotificationView:ember1181>)